# How can i send my motion tracking project with the background video to a render farm?

Tags: tracking

Is there any way to pack a video file with a blender file in motion tracking, and send it to a render farm?

Comment: That's gonna be specific to the render farm as they have to unpack/save your project somewhere in a file structure before rendering. Did you ask them? They probably have a way to add files in the same "folder" or somewhere around your blender file location.

Comment: Packing does not work with video files. Most likely you need to put the video file in the same folder as the blend file,  then set the project to relative folders. You can then compress the folder containing everything as a Zip file and upload that to the render farm. But ultimately it depends on the render farm you want to use. Consult with them directly.